Prevent new-line characters in a multiline raw string literal
How can I define raw string literal where the line breaks in the code are just for readability and there are no new-line characters (\r, \n) in the resulting string?
Something like this:
string str =
    """
    first line;
    also first line
    """;

should result in "first line;also first line".
So far this is what I've come up with, but it's pretty ugly:
str =
    $"""
    first line;{""
    }also first line
    """;

At least it's a bit less verbose than:
str =
    """
    first line;
    """ +
    """
    also first line
    """;

A popular LLM told me that in C# I can just use \ at the very end of a line in a raw string literal in order to prevent new-line characters, but that doesn't seem to work because the backslash just gets treated literally.

Why not use normal "..." strings and concatenate them?

@Progman Because my actual strings contain many " which would need to be escaped if not using raw string literals, making it harder to read.

You can also use single-line raw strings: """The "ultimate" test"""

@OlivierJacot-Descombes Yes, but that would become a very long line in my specific case and pretty unreadable.

What I mean: """The "ultimate" test""" +  on the next line """another string""" +  on the next line """yet "another" string""";

@OlivierJacot-Descombes Yes, thanks. That solution I already included in my question.

That solution I already included in my question. -- you used multiline raw string literals in your question.  Using single-line raw string literals with compile-time concatenation as @OlivierJacot-Descombes suggests should be both brief and performant.

@dbc I get it now, thanks. Yes, that looks like it's the best compile-time solution.

public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string WithoutNewlines(this string input)
    {
        return input.Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r", "");
    }
}

public static void Main()
{
    string str =
    """
    first line;
    also first line
    """.WithoutNewlines();
    
    Console.WriteLine(str);
}


The disadvantage of this approach is that it replaces compile time string concatenation with runtime string replacement.  Even though this is what the querent asked for, it's a performance hit that brings no real advantage.
